# Matching Acronyms to their long form

Tags: python, text-extraction

Trying to match Acronyms to their meaning- both the acronym and the meaning are in the same document, and usually not that far from one another.

for example for this sample of text:

> > (b) each American Depositary Share, representing two Class A Shares (each, an “ ADS ”), issued and outstanding immediately prior to the Effective Time (other than, if any, ADSs representing the Excluded Shares) shall be cancelled in exchange for the right to receive US$12.25 in cash per ADS without interest (the “ Per ADS Merger Consideration ”) (less US$0.05 per ADS cancellation fees), payable pursuant to the terms and conditions set forth in the Deposit Agreement, and each Class A Share represented by such ADSs shall be cancelled and cease to exist, in exchange for the right of the Depositary, as the registered holder thereof, to receive the Per Share Merger Consideration, which the Depositary will distribute to the holders of such ADSs as the Per ADS Merger Consideration pursuant to the terms and conditions set forth in this Agreement and the Deposit Agreement (less US$0.05 per ADS cancellation fees); provided , that in the event of any conflict between this Agreement and the Deposit Agreement, this Agreement shall prevail;

The acronym is "ADS" and its meaning is "American Depositary Share".

I started building a regex based on tokenizing the acronym- so it would look like this `"[A].+?[D].+?[S].+?\b"` and that is working for the example above but I am look for a more- **"python-y"** way of doing this because of variations in the types of acronyms I see.

Examples:

1)Upon the terms and subject to the conditions set forth in this Agreement, and in accordance with the **Companies Law (2018 Revision) of the Cayman Islands** (the “ CICL ”)- would match CLCI but not CICL

2)Each of the consolidated financial statements (including, in each case, any notes thereto) contained in or incorporated by reference into the Company SEC Reports was prepared in accordance with United States **generally accepted accounting principles** (“ GAAP ”) - Capitals vs lowercase and would like to add United States as well.

Comment: Do you know all the potential variations of the acronyms? I assume by variation you don't also refer to morphing of acronyms  to something like plural "ADSs"

Comment: By variations I just meant ones that are exact "letter to word" and ones that are not. I just need to detect that "ADS" is "American Depositary Share" so that every other place I see "ADS" I can do some magical CSS to do a hover over it to show the match. 

So I can find the original "ADS"- it will only appear in quotes once and only really need to concern myself with the text that comes before that index to find my match.

Comment: I guess you will have less stress writing something that query and scrap [Acronym Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com) for definitions.

Comment: @accdias but then for example ADS returns 183 results, so I need to loop through those and see which results is closest to the text I am already trying to grab out of the text before "ADS", and "CICL" or "CLCI" did not return the result I would be looking for

Comment: Indeed but still easier to program something like that than try to create a regex that matches every single case you will have.

Comment: I wonder if you could use the sentence tokenizer from NLTK to split into sentences, then check for a regex to match the `" ???? "` pattern in each sentence to at least narrow the search space and reduce false positives...maybe then split on `'('` to separate acronym from sentence?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few regex formats that can match these exact specifications, and they are created dynamically based on the existing acronyms from the text. The problem is that trying to match varying formats like ***CICL*** for ***Companies Law (2018 Revision) of the Cayman Islands*** means that the regex should look for extended words between **Companies**, **Law**, **Cayman** and **Islands**, and it must be kind of generic because an example of a long extended version could be ***Ministry of the Financials and Treasury for Regional and State Acquisitions***, you never know when it's the case. So if I were to search for MFTRSA and I have a phrase like ***`m`other asked `f`ather `t`o `r`aise `s`ome `a`wareness***, then obviously that will be a match

At the end of the script you will get something like: 
`{'ADS': ('American Depositary Share', 9)}` which shows what acronmy was used to detect the long version, the long version and the starting index of the long text. Also you will get the unmatched acronyms.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations
import re

ACRONYM_PATTERN = "[A-Z]{2,}"

text = "in the Ministry of Noodles (cooked 1808) and External Amicalities ordonance 46 has been ratified because the Chief Hunter Gatherer also known as CHG found a SGC in the Left Chamber (LC) in the second part of the trimestrial chicken fight. the CHG also aclaimed that the members of the MNEA are no longer fit to eat noodles because the LC's color had turned into green. Long live the queen and may the MNEA get morphed into a duck!"


# detect all acronyms in the text
detected_acronyms = re.finditer(ACRONYM_PATTERN, text)
detected_acronyms_indexes = defaultdict(list)

for a in detected_acronyms:
    detected_acronyms_indexes[a.group()].append(a.start())

acronyms_set = set(detected_acronyms_indexes.keys())

x = []

# create regex patterns for all acronyms
acronyms_patterns = defaultdict(list)
for acronym in acronyms_set:
    # uppercase strict pattern
    words = "".join([r"[{}]\w+ ".format(c) for c in acronym])
    pattern = "{}".format(words)
    acronyms_patterns[acronym].append(pattern.strip())

    # uppercase extended pattern
    words = []
    acronym_len = len(acronym)
    for i, c in enumerate(acronym):
        word = r"[{}]\w+ ".format(c)
        if i + 1 < acronym_len:
            word += "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)]+ ){0,3}"
        words.append(word)

    pattern = "{}".format("".join(words))
    acronyms_patterns[acronym].append(pattern.strip())

    # lowercase strict
    words = "".join([r"[{}]\w+ ".format(c) for c in acronym.lower()])
    pattern = "{}".format(words)
    acronyms_patterns[acronym].append(pattern.strip())

    # lowercase extended pattern
    words = []
    acronym_len = len(acronym)
    for i, c in enumerate(acronym.lower()):
        word = r"[{}]\w+ ".format(c)
        if i + 1 < acronym_len:
            word += "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)]+ ){0,3}"
        words.append("".join(word))

    pattern = "{}".format("".join(words))
    acronyms_patterns[acronym].append(pattern.strip())

# use the patterns to detect the longer versions in the text
original_text_indexes = {}
for acronym, patterns_list in acronyms_patterns.items():
    for pattern in patterns_list:
        result = re.search(pattern.replace("\\\\", "\\"), text)

        if result is None:
            continue

        original_text_indexes[acronym] = (result.group(), result.start())

print("Detected long versions")
print(original_text_indexes)

print("\nUnmatched acronyms")
print(acronyms_set.difference(set(original_text_indexes.keys())))
```

Comment: @user2183943 did this help you?